# How to set TextView text size using ZoomControls in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I want to Dynamically adjust TextView textsize in Android Application.

For this I am setting ClickListener for ZoomControls using following  method.

I am getting correct output for zooming in action.

But for zooming out, I am not getting correct output. The Text size increases instead. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Please Help.

```
   public void SetZoomControls()
{
     //Zoom refers to ZoomControls
    //main_code refers to a TextView
    Zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
      float previous=  main_code.getTextSize();
            previous++;
      main_code.setTextSize(previous);
            Toast.makeText(code_display.this, String.valueOf(main_code.getTextSize()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    Zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            float previous1=  main_code.getTextSize();
            main_code.setTextSize(main_code.getTextSize()-1);
            Toast.makeText(code_display.this,String.valueOf( previous1),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using this method  `setTextSize(int size)`, the unit type by default is `"sp"` or `"scaled pixels"`.

You can use `setTextSize(int unit, float size)` to specify a unit type.The constant values for this can be found in the `TypedValue` class

```
TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX   //Pixels

TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP   //Scaled Pixels
```

Comment: @AkshayPatel glad to help you.